# Searching for Des Moines, IA thinks I'm in Israel

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I search for jobs in [Des Moines, IA](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=Des%20Moines,%20IA), Careers thinks I mean Northern Israel?

[image: bug]

this doesn't seem correct. [Des Moines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_Moines,_Iowa) is the capital of the State of Iowa. Other cities in Iowa, such as [Ames](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Ames%2C+IA), appear to work just fine.

Comment: I was assuming that it was due to ISO-3166-2 trickery (either IA is the key for Israel, or IA is the northern province of Israel or something) but that [doesn't seem to be the case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:IL).

Comment: other cities in Iowa, such as [Ames](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Ames%2C+IA), appear to work just fine.

Comment: Perhaps Des Moines is the site of a top-secret transporter project that created a wormhole to Northern, Israel that was leaked on to the internet and infected the SO database to assume that Northern Israel is within 20 miles of Des Moines? Otherwise, it may just be a bug. But the wormhole theory seems more plausible.

Comment: @jmac that makes a lot of sense. This fits as well:  http://www.ufosightingsdaily.com/2012/10/ufo-chased-by-two-black-helicopters.html

Comment: @jmac Nope, it's our geo data from Yahoo getting mucked up. Usually just takes a cache clean up. I'll get someone on it.

Comment: @Juice, *"Caching"* and *"Yahoo"*? Sounds like the coverup of a wormhole to me. Occam's Razor, and all that.

Comment: @jmac I'm no programmer, I do supporty things. I really just string together words I hear the devs say to make up plausible excuses. Kidding........ sorta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another case of a bad cached value.  It's been cleared out and should be working again.

I'm adding some logging to help us identify where these are coming from.